# .rvmrc does not auto switch when opening a new tab ( lion os x )

Tags: macos, terminal, rvm

With Mac OS X Lion, when I create a new tab in Terminal, and I am within the same directory as my .rvmrc file, the new tab is automatically the same directory, and the .rvmrc automatically switches my Ruby.

However, after I changed my RVM ( downgraded to 1.6 ), when I open a new tab, it does not automatically auto load this .rvmrc file.

How can I make it automatically change my rubies when creating a new terminal tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM does not support old releases, the reason is - it was already fixed and works as expected in new version.

You should update to new RVM and it will work as expected.

In case you have troubles updating RVM try this:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto
```

And open new terminal window.